# XSL Transformation - JAXPSAXProcessor

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt

I have the below simple xslt and the input xml, doing the transformation in eclipse Mars... However when I run this getting "String Index out of range error"

Could anyone lease give a hint on the fix? Is it because of the date function?

xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Top" mode="create"/>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="Top"  mode="create">
    <Root>


      <body>

        <out>
          <Temp>

            <Temp1>

              <data>
                <xsl:value-of select="date:date()"/>
              </data>
            </Temp1>
          </Temp>
        </out>
      </body>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml

```
<Top></Top>
```

error in eclipse after transform - Eclipse Mars, xml perspective, JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.ExsltDatetime.date(Unknown Source)
    at map_getLoanAgmt_to_manageLoanAgmtPHStatement_MF_req_1.template$dot$1()
    at map_getLoanAgmt_to_manageLoanAgmtPHStatement_MF_req_1.applyTemplates1()
    at map_getLoanAgmt_to_manageLoanAgmtPHStatement_MF_req_1.template$dot$0()
    at map_getLoanAgmt_to_manageLoanAgmtPHStatement_MF_req_1.applyTemplates()
    at map_getLoanAgmt_to_manageLoanAgmtPHStatement_MF_req_1.transform()
```

**EDIT**

I changed the processor for  XSL to Xalan 2.7.1, in Eclipse. However it still doesnt work.

Comment: Where is your Java code that processes the transform?

Comment: I just use XML Perspective in the eclipse, run as xslt transformation on the xsl by selecting the input xml

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3p uses Xalan 2.7.1 and runes fine there.